# ASP.Net break point set but not firing in visual studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I've got a old asp.net project that I'm having trouble getting the breakpoints to hit when I open it in Visual Studio 2019.

It just seems to step over the breakpoints.

The project is set to Debug mode, I've also checked the output window and the symbols are being loaded.

If I add in the following line of the code

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

It will break, but if I remove the above line of code the break point on the next line does not get hit.

Has anyone else experienced behaviour like this and did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: I tried all the steps below and none of them worked, I'm just in the process of creating an new empty project and copying my source into it to see if it will hit breakpoints in the new project.

Comment: If I copy the same code into a new project that is created in 2019 I can debug.

Comment: Based on your description, the construction of the old project is different from VS2019. One more thing, you can also try to disable the option under `Require source files that exactly match the original version` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General` in the old project.Hint from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/troubleshooting-breakpoints?view=vs-2019#-the-current-source-code-is-different-from-the-version-built-into).  Anyway, since you have a solution, I suggest you could add it as answer. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone else experienced behaviour like this and did you manage to
>   solve the problem?

Please try these:

**1)** delete all breakpoints under `Debug`-->`Delete all breakpoints`

**2)** check `Managed Compatibility Mode` under `Tools`->`Options`->`Debugging`-->`General`

and check `Enable .NET Framework source stepping` under `Tools`->`Options`->`Debugging`->`General`

**3)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder,`bin`,`obj` folder under the path of your project and then restart your project.

**4)** Right-click on your project-->`Properties`-->`Build`-->choose `Optimize Code`.

**In addition**, if these do not work, Running the VS command prompt as admin and then runn [devenv /setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/devenv-command-line-switches-for-vspackage-development?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was ridiculous, in the emulator the network data was off, turning it on solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools >> Option >> Debugging >> General.
Check the option -"Supress JIT Optimization..."

It enabled now to hit every line after breakpoint.

Comment: It would be better to include screenshots of Visual Studio and provide more details on why this option could be helpful and the reasons behind it.